# Show Varnish 'Age:' in production mode

Tags: magento2, varnish

Is it possible to show the varnish 'Age:' header in production mode. I want to be able to monitor how long our pages are staying in Varnish cache for.

This header is only visible in developer mode on our site at the moment

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can see headers in configuration file:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish6.vcl#L193

you can manipulate headers in varnish by commenting them or using `set` `unset` parameter.